# Calling Video With fancybox and XML

Tags: xml, video, fancybox, shadowbox

I am wanting to use fancybox since shadowbox-js.com is no longer available. I use it for displaying images and videos. Right now I have my coding in shadowbox set so it uses a specific player that uses an old jwplayer skin that calls up an xml file that has the poster images and and videos in the xml file. The code I use is below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../shadowbox/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../shadowbox/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    Shadowbox.init({
language: 'en',
players:  ['img', 'html', 'iframe', 'qt', 'wmp', 'swf', 'flv', 'mp4', 'php'],
overlayOpacity: '0.90',
continuous: 'true',
counterType: 'default',
animSequence: 'wh',
handleOversize: 'resize',
modal: 'false',
flashVars: {skin: '../jwplayer/skins/norden/norden.zip'}
 
                       });
</script>
```

The link coding for calling up the videos looks like:

```html
<a href="/jwplayer/player.swf?file=videos/xml/jw_player2.xml" rel="shadowbox[Mixed];width=1280;height=720" title="World of Tanks - Official Video Trailers"><img src="images/wot-logo-dark-w-101-logo-600x253.png" border="0" width="600" height="253" title="" alt="101 ABGC Logo" /></a>
```

You can see an example of what I am talking about at http://101abgc.mywebteks.net/ just click the World of Tanks logo to see what I am talking about.

I want to be able to do the same thing with fancybox as I do with shadowbox for calling up the xml file to play the videos and still use the jwplayer skin I have in the code. Is this possible with fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

The way I use jwplayer with fancybox is by putting the jwplayer code inside of a hidden div that also has the fancybox div and then the link will link to that inner div.

```
<a href="#video" id="popup" title="World of Tanks - Official Video Trailers">
    <img src="images/wot-logo-dark-w-101-logo-600x253.png" border="0" width="600" height="253" title="" alt="101 ABGC Logo" />
</a>

<div style="position:absolute; display:none;">
<div id="video" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="fancy">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer('fancy').setup({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '16:9',
        'file': '[insert video file here]',    
        'image': '[insert video still here]',
        'autostart': 'false',
        'skin': '/jwplayer/player.swf?file=videos/xml/jw_player2.xml',
    });
  </script>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup").fancybox({ // matches the selector of the fancybox links
        'titlePosition' : 'inside',
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'autoScale' : false,
        'autoDimensions' : false
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'll try that but looking at the code it doesn't appear to look like that will work. The xml file contains all the images and locations of the video files and is not the skin. The skin for the player is ../jwplayer/skins/norden/norden.zip and if I use your code I have to add the images and videos all individually instead of being called up with the xml file that contains the playlist of all the videos that you can play using the player controls.

Comment: I tried the code you gave above and it did not work for the reasons I stated. I am still trying to get fancybox to work with an xml file that has all the videos and poster images for the videos. I can get a php page to open that has the videos being called up from the xml file but I use an iframe call in the fancybox code and when I call up the php page, half the video player is blocked out. I am looking to see where I can edit the dimensions for using "fancybox. fancybox.iframe"